# Get element value from xml file using Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I need to extract/modify an element from a .xml file using Python. For this, I am using the xml.etree.ElementTree but I don't get the desired output from my code. I need to extract the element "address" (in this case 10.25.0.0) from the .xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<esc
    xmlns="http://www.test.com/esc/esc">
    <tenants>
        <tenant>
            <name>esc</name>
            <deployments>
                <deployment>
                    <name>xyz1000_Test_v1</name>
                    <networks>
                        <network>
                            <name>tenant_1</name>
                            <admin_state>true</admin_state>
                            <subnet>
                                <name>tenant_1_sub</name>
                                <ipversion>ipv4</ipversion>
                                **<address>10.25.0.0</address>**
                            </subnet>
                        </network>
                        <network> .....
```

The code I'm using is the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('csr1kv_file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
ET.register_namespace("","http://www.test.com/esc/esc")

for subnet in root.iter('address'):
    print (subnet)
```

Out of the code I get no error and no value (10.25.0.0 as desired). Can somebody please give me an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`register_namespace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace) has no effect when you iterate over or search an XML document. That function only applies when serializing (writing to file).

Just change

```
for subnet in root.iter('address'):
```

to

```
for subnet in root.iter('{http://www.test.com/esc/esc}address'):
```

Output:

```
<Element '{http://www.test.com/esc/esc}address' at 0x030F3CF0>
(and possibly more address elements)
```

---

To get the value of the element in the output, use `print(subnet.text)`.

To set a new value of the element, assign to `subnet.text`:

```
subnet.text = "whatever"
```

Comment: Thanks! And what if I need to change the element "name" from "deployment"? As you can see in the code, the element ''name'' is under ''deployment'' and ''subnet''. When I apply "for DeploymentName in root.iter('{http://www.test.com/esc/esc}name'):", it change the obviously the four elements.

Comment: Ok. The original questions is already answered. Thanks a lot. I've already posted the new one since I'm still having troubles to access other child elements, even with the "find' function.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not what you expect, but you can always try that way:

```
with open('csr1kv_file.xml') as f:
     address = str(f.read()).split("<address>")[1].split("</address>")[0]
```

*Edit: I'm answering here, the comment section is a pain to deal with*

If you want to change the < address > value with something else, you can try:

```
    with open('csr1kv_file.xml') as f:
        address = str(f.read()).split("<address>")[1].split("</address>")[0]
        f_update = str(f.read()).replace("<address>" + str(address) + "</address>", "<address> whatever_address_you_want </address>")

    with open('csr1kv_file.xml', 'w') as f2:
        f2.write(f_update)
```

*Edit number 2:*
This one is working properly on my machine with the sample data that you provide:

```
with open('csr1kv_file.xml') as f:
    full = f.read()
    address = str(full).split("<address>")[1].split("</address>")[0]    

f.close()

f_update = str(full).replace("<address>" + str(address) + "</address>","<address>whatever_ip</address>")

with open('csr1kv_file.xml', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(f_update)

f2.close()
```

Comment: It's actually useful Guillaume. Thanks. What if I want to modify the value within "address"? How can I do that?

Comment: I've edited my answer, let me know if it match your needs

Comment: Thanks for the update Guillaume, but the change part is not working for me. It doesn't give any error, but nothing is modified.

Comment: My bad, I've update it again, it should work fine now ;)

Comment: Treating an XML file like a plain text file is fragile and error-prone. XML is a structured format that is best processed using proper XML tools (such as ElementTree).